# Unable to communicate with my .compute file with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compute-shader

I'm experimenting with the *Compute Shader* with Unity, and I don't understand why nothing changes when I communicate with it in a C# script.

C# script file:

```cs
ComputeBuffer squareBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(_square.Length, sizeof(float) * 16);
    
squareBuffer.SetData(_square);

_computeShader.SetFloats("width", width);
_computeShader.SetBuffer(0, "squares", squareBuffer);
_computeShader.Dispatch(0, 8, 1, 1);

for (int i = 0; i < _objects.Count; ++i) 
{
    GameObject obj = _objects[i];
    Square square = _square[i];

    Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
            
    mesh.vertices = new Vector3[]
    {
        square.firstTriangle.firstPoint,
        square.firstTriangle.secondPoint,
        square.secondTriangle.firstPoint,
        square.secondTriangle.secondPoint
    };

    mesh.triangles = _SQUARETRANGLE;

    obj.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
    obj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", square.color);
}
```

Compute shader file:

```
#pragma kernel CSMain

struct Square 
{
    float3 firstTrianglePoint0, firstTrianglePoint1;
    float3 secondtTrianglePoint0, secondTrianglePoint1;

    float4 color;
};

RWStructuredBuffer<Square> squares;

float width;

[numthreads(8, 1, 1)]
void CSMain (uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    Square square = squares[id.x];

    square.firstTrianglePoint0 = float3(-width / 2, 0, -width / 2);
    square.firstTrianglePoint1 = float3(-width / 2, 0, width / 2);

    square.secondtTrianglePoint0 = float3(width / 2, 0, -width / 2);
    square.secondTrianglePoint1 = float3(width / 2, 0, -width / 2);

    square.color = float4(0.13f, 0.7450f, 0.133f, 0.5175f);

    squares[id.x] = square;
}
```

The values don't seem to want to change. For example, the default value for color is float4(0f). After calling the compute shader, the color values are always equal to float4(0f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the Dispatch, you forgot to get the data back to your buffer (squareBuffer) by calling [GetData](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ComputeBuffer.GetData.html)

```
squareBuffer.GetData(_square);
```